# Which Material 3 color attribute should be used to match the background of the Android 13 settings screen?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I would like to know which Material 3 color attribute should be used to match the background color of the stock Android 13 settings screen:

[image]

I've tried with several but I can't find one that matches.

```kotlin
Column(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
) {
    repeat(5) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant),
        ) { Text("surfaceVariant") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer),
        ) { Text("primaryContainer") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
        ) { Text("secondaryContainer") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer),
        ) { Text("tertiaryContainer") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outlineVariant),
        ) { Text("outlineVariant") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(1.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(1.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(2.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(2.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(4.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(4.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(5.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(5.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(6.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(6.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(7.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(7.dp)") }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(72.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(8.dp)),
        ) { Text("surfaceColorAtElevation(8.dp)") }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's using `inverseOnSurface` for light theme and `background` for dark theme:
[image]
[image]

```kotlin
val settingsBackgroundColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
} else {
    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface
}
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(settingsBackgroundColor),
)
```